# Laravel 5.3 Eloquent - How to post data to multiple tables with a form?

Tags: php, laravel

So far I can only post data to 1 table with a form.

My controller:

```
public function store(Request $request, Role $role)
{   
    $role->fill($request->all());  

    $role->save();

    return redirect('/roles');
}
```

My view:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="name-input">@lang('role.name')</label>
    <input id="name-input" type="text" name="name" class="form-control" value="{{ isset($role) ? $role->name : '' }}" autofocus>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="description-input">@lang('role.description_optional')</label>
    <textarea id="description-input" name="description" class="form-control">{{ isset($role) ? $role->description : '' }}</textarea>                        
</div>
```

So it perfectly stores the `name` and `description`, but what if I wanted to store data to a second table?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
$second = new SecondTableModel(); 
$second->fill($request->all());  
$second->save();
```

Comment: The Eloquent Model constructor does the filling for you so  `new SecondTableModel($request->all())` is good